# Automate the rights

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use the SQL Developer to connect with Oracle.

I try to "automate" the rights, that means that I do not need all the time to type in every GRANT comment for every table and every user. So my idea was to make three tables. One owns the table names which exists in the database, and a tablegroup. One owns all the users and one the rights with rightgroups.

Now I try to automate it, to put it in one grant. Like:

```
GRANT (Select rights from DB_Rights where rightgroup = 1)
    ON (Select tables from DB_Tables where Tablegroup = 1) to (User)
```

But it didn't work. Where is my mistake? Or isn't this possible? Is there another option to "automate" it?

Comment: i think you want to look into [ROLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authorization.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be similar to this. You still have to write the right SELECT query but you should get an idea how it works.

```
BEGIN
   FOR aGRANT IN (
       Select rights, tables, User_NAME 
       from DB_Rights 
          CROSS JOIN DB_Tables 
       where Tablegroup = 1 AND rightgroup = 1 AND Tablegroup = 1) 
    LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT '||aGRANT.rights||' ON '||aGRANT.tables||' TO '||aGRANT.User_NAME;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

In order to verify your command replace `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ...` by `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(...);`

In general consider the usage of `ROLES` as suggested by tbone. However, there are situations where ROLES are not applicable or end up in "automate grants for ROLES" instead of "automate grants for USERS"

Comment: On of the variations of this that I have used is to generate the DDL to be executed in the SQL statement itself. The advantage is that it can make debugging easier for complex DDL as you can just execute the SQL and inspect/execute the result. It's all good though.

Comment: @S.iggi: if this was the answer, would you consider accepting it? To do so, click on the tick mark to the left, so it is marked as resolved.